# Can I safely update Apache Superset via pip?

Tags: apache-superset

I am currently running an outdated version of Apache Superset 0.20.4. The Superset DB contains a substantial amount of slices and dashboards. I would like to update my version.

Can I just run an upgrade from pip? Is any of you aware of any backward incompatibility that would prevent me from reading the Superset DB after the update?

Answer (score 5):

Answering my own question, there is no problem in upgrading but one has to run the DB migration `superset db upgrade`.